# Signification de « La seule figure aimante de la maison aux yeux du petit garçon est son père » ?

Tags: sens, syntaxe, reformulation

Je ne sais pas si j'ai bien compris cette phrase :

> La seule figure aimante de la maison aux yeux du petit garçon est son père.

Comment dire la même chose de façon différente ? Est-ce que ça veut dire que selon le petit garçon, la seule personne de la maison qui l'aime est son père ? Donc, il lui semble que son père est la seule personne qui  l'aime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu as bien compris le sens de la phrase.

*Figure* signifie ici d'abord *visage* (donc: visage souriant, affectueux) et, dans une deuxième étape, par métonymie ou synecdoque, la personne à qui ce visage appartient.

> Aux yeux du petit garçon, le seul visage souriant et affectueux de la maison est celui de son père.

En anglais, on aurait pu écrire, *loving face*.

Answer (score 2):

C'est aussi simple que vous le supposez ; le mot « figure » est expliqué par la division « **III B 1 a** » de cette entrée du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/figure) ;

> B. P. méton. Personne caractéristique.
>   1. Personne caractéristique ayant, ou ayant eu, une existence réelle.
>   a) Individu marquant, célèbre.
>
> - Figure historique, idéale; grande, sinistre, sublime figure.
> - On retrouve entre les deux figures [de Napoléon et de Louis Bonaparte], entre leurs situations et leurs époques, la plus constante analogie. (PROUDHON, Révol. soc., 1852, p. 154)
> - C'est une figure extraordinairement séduisante que celle de ce protestant que l'abbé Bremond appelait un grand homme  (GREEN, Journal, 1949, p. 330)
> - Quel malheur que alors que j'étais seulement préoccupé de retrouver Gilberte ou Albertine je n'aie pas fait plus attention à ce monsieur! Je l'avais pris pour un raseur du monde, pour un simple figurant, c'était une figure!
>     PROUST, Le Temps retr., 1922, p. 720.

Le petit garçon ne pense peut-être pas tout à fait en termes de relations parentales mais il identifie des personnes (des figures) qui suscitent à leur contact certaines émotions. Les expositions à la personne de son père étaient en quelque sorte accompagnées dans son esprit par l'idée générale des bienfaits à son égard plutôt que par l'idée abstraite de son père qu'il se serait fait s'il avait été  plus âgé ou déjà adolescent. Il personnifiait plus ou moins l'affection. Une paraphrase littéraire est assez difficile à produire ;

Il me semble que l'idée suivante conserve l'idée initiale de personnification.

- Aux yeux du petit garçon seul son père dans la maison incarnait l'affection.